# Using keyboard shortcut for entering password while entering SSH session

Tags: centos, ssh, keyboard-shortcuts

I am using CentOS, and as part of my job, I need to log into multiple SSH sessions (servers) on a daily basis, which requires entering the password every time. I have been wondering if there is a way to automate the process of entering the password by pressing a specific key, such as `F12`.

I attempted to bind the key using the `bashrc` file, but it doesn't appear to be working.

Comment: Hi, in this case you should probably use keypairs and add your public key once in ~/.ssh/authorized_keys (can be done from local with ssh-copy-id) on the remote machines and you will be able to login without pass.

Comment: Sadly, I'm trying for something other than this!. I was thinking if a Keyboard shortcut could possibly enter the password on terminal ?

Comment: Entering passwords automatically using a keyboard shortcut can be a security risk as it exposes your password to potential vulnerabilities. Why choose one method that is more insecure than the other? Use public-key authentication instead, which provides a more secure and convenient method! You can easy create an alias with a public-key authentication  to login.